# Express .map function not returning values

Tags: jquery, express, sequelize.js, lodash

I have some jquery in my view file where I want to take all of the values of the individual fields with the name, `discoverySource`. The solution thanks to some help from a stack user was to use the `lodash` module and then map the array into individual values to be appropriately used for my sequelize BulkCreate function. With my current post setup, the .map method correctly creates individual rows in my db based on the amount of fields filled in, but for some reason the values aren't being passed. I am not sure the reason this is happening because the body-parser value is correct and the values are being logged correctly everywhere outside of the variable that is being set.  I commented next to each console.log to show what values are returned. My issue is that I receive `undefined` and `[object Object]` for the map method. Website 1, Website 2, Website 3, were my test values for the fields

**Here is my route:**

```
.post(function(req, res){
        console.log(req.body.discoverySource); //[ 'Website 1', 'Website 2', 'Website 3' ]

    var sources = _.map(req.body.discoverySource, function (source) {
        return {
             discoverySource: source,
             organizationId: req.body.organizationId
        };
    });
    console.log("These are the" + sources); //These are the[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

    console.log(sources.discoverySource); //undefined
    console.log(sources.organizationId); //undefined
    models.DiscoverySource.bulkCreate(sources)
    .then(function(){
        return models.DiscoverySource.findAll();
    }).then(function(discoverySource){
        console.log(discoverySource);
        res.redirect('/app');
    }).catch(function(error){
        res.send(error);
        console.log('Error during Post: ' + error);
    });
});
```

**Here is my view:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  {{> head}}
</head>

<body>
  {{> navigation}}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <form action="/app/sign-up/organization" method="post">
        <p>{{user.email}}</p>
        <input type="hidden" name="admin" value="{{user.email}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="organizationId">
        <label for="sign-up-organization">Test Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sign-up-organization" name="organizationName" value="" placeholder="Company/Organization">
        <a href="#" id="sign-up-add-discovery-source">Add Another</a>
        <div id="sign-up-organization-discovery-source">
          <input type="text" id="discovery-source-field" placeholder="Discovery Source" name="discoverySource[0]">
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <a href="/login">Already have an account? Login here!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var dataSourceField = $('#sign-up-organization-discovery-source');
      var i = $('#sign-up-organization-discovery-source p').size();
      var sourceCounter = 1;

      $('#sign-up-add-discovery-source').on('click', function() {
        $('<p><label for="discovery-source-field"><input type="text" id="discovery-source-field" size="20" name="discoverySource[{' + sourceCounter+++'}]" value="" placeholder="Discovery Source" /></label> <a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(dataSourceField);
        i++;
        return false;
      });
      $('#sign-up-organization-discovery-source').on('click', '.remove', function() {
        if (i > 1) {
          $(this).parent('p').remove();
          i--;
        }
        return false;
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bulkCreate() you need to pass the array directly.

```
models.DiscoverySource.bulkCreate(sources)
```

The pattern is:

```
Model.bulkCreate(<array_of_values);
```

as documented here: http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model/#bulkcreaterecords-options-promisearrayinstance

Comment: Ben, sorry I was running my own tests, I updated the code to use `sources`, but situation has not changed. Exact same issue as I had before

Answer (score 1):

This:-

```
return {
     discoverySource: source,
     organizationId: req.body.organizationId
};
```

creates an object with 2 properties, `discoverySource` and `organizationId`.

So `sources` is an array of objects. `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`

This:-

```
console.log(sources.discoverySource); //undefined
console.log(sources.organizationId); //undefined
```

is `undefined` because you are looking for `discoverySource` and `organizationId` on the array, and not on an object in the array.

try:-

```
console.log(sources[0].discoverySource); //discoverySource on 1st object in the array
console.log(sources[0].organizationId); //organizationIdon 1st object in the array
```